# Overflow hidden not working as expected on inline items

Tags: css

I am trying to hide items that are wider than parent's width. Here's a codepen URL: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMEbrY . As you can see, the children break on new lines while I want them to stay on same line.

```
.a {
  width: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b, .c {
  display: inline;
}

.b {

}

.c {

}
```

Comment: You can add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.a` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```css
.a {
  width: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.b, .c {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">500</div>
  <div class="c">501</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent container

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQGRdO

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space:nowrap` this will cut all the overflowing elements out of its jurisdiction

```css
.a {
  width: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.b, .c {
  display: inline;
}

.b {
  
}

.c {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">500</div>
  <div class="c">501</div>
</div>
```